# Сервис использует все ресурсы

Tags: c#, service, smtp, windows-service

Я написал свой СМТП-сервис (windows-сервис), который через сетки после запуска и работы скушал 96% мощности сервака, где размещен.

**Вопрос - подскажите, как уменьшить потребляемые ресурсы?**

Вот код:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpHelper s = new SmtpHelper(this);
                Thread listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Listen));
                listen.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry( ServiceName + " error: \n" + ex.ToString());
            }        
        }
```

потом:

```
public void Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                l.WriteEvent("***************START*******************");
                l.WriteEvent("SMTP server started " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                SMTP_Listener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    /*
                     Создадим сначала номер потока и файл логов для него                     
                     */
                    Socket clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();

                    //номер сессии(клиента)
                    _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();
                    _email.sessionId = Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId);

                    l.WriteEvent("Создан поток для обработки клиента: " + _sessionId);

                    //запускаем обработку клиента
                    var processor = new ClientProcessor(clientSocket, m_ConnectedIp, m_ConnectedHostName, _email,
                        MaxMessageSize, CommandIdleTimeOut);
                    processor._sessionId = _sessionId;

                    UserSessionController.AddSession(Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId));

                    Thread newClient = new Thread(processor.StartProcessing);
                    newClient.Name = _sessionId;
                    //newClient.IsBackground = true; // ???
                    newClient.Start();

                  //  l.WriteEvent("*********************************************************");
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
            {
                l.WriteEvent("SMTP Listen ThreadInterruptedException: " + e.ToString());
                l.WriteLogEvent("SMTP Listen ThreadInterruptedException: " + e.ToString(), _email);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                l.WriteEvent("SMTP Listen Error: " + ex.ToString());
                l.WriteLogEvent("SMTP Listen Error: " + ex.ToString(), _email);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Каждый клиент обрабатывается в своем потоке.

```
public void StartProcessing()
{
    try
    {
        string namethread = _sessionId;

        _connectedIp = ParseIP_from_EndPoint(_clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        _connectedHostName = GetHostName(_connectedIp);

        l.WriteEvent(String.Format("Клиент {0}: _connectedIp = {1}, _connectedHostName = {2}", _sessionId, _connectedIp,
            _connectedHostName), namethread);

        _email.ip = _connectedIp;
        _email.port = 25;

        SendData("220 " + Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready\r\n");//  l.WriteEvent("'220 " + Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready' были отправлены клиенту", namethread);

        //ЦИКЛ ПРИЕМА КОМАНД ОТ КОНКРЕТНОГО КЛИЕНТА
        while (true){
            //если есть данные, то считаем их
            if (_clientSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                //чтение команды клиента
                string lastCmd = ReadLine();

                //парсим команду
                if (lastCmd.Trim() != String.Empty)
                    ProceedCommand(lastCmd, namethread);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        l.WriteEvent("SMTP StartProcessing Error: " + ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Обработка команд клиента:

```
/// <summary>
/// Обработка команд сервиса
/// </summary>
/// <param name="SMTP_commandTxt">текст команды клиента </param>
private void ProceedCommand(string SMTP_commandTxt, string threadName)
{
    //обработчик клиентских команд
    CommandWorking _commandWorking = new CommandWorking(_connectedIp, _maxMessageSize, _connectedHostName, _clientSocket, _commandIdleTimeOut, _email, l);

    //парсим команду
    string[] cmdParts = SMTP_commandTxt.TrimStart().Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    //текст команды
    string SMTP_command = cmdParts[0].ToUpper().Trim();

    //аргументы команды
    string argsText = GetArgsText(SMTP_commandTxt, SMTP_command);
    //debug:
    //l.WriteEvent("SMTP комманда: " + SMTP_command + "  " + argsText, threadName);

    //Ответ нашего сервера на каждую команду клиента
    string answer = String.Empty;

    switch (SMTP_command)
    {
        case "HELO":
            answer = _commandWorking.HELO();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "EHLO":
            answer = _commandWorking.EHLO();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "AUTH":
            answer = _commandWorking.AUTH();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "MAIL":
            answer = _commandWorking.MAIL();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "RCPT":
            answer = _commandWorking.RCPT(argsText, threadName);

            if (answer.Split('|').Count() == 2)
            {
                string sendData = answer.Split('|')[0].ToString();
                SendData(sendData);
                //получатель почты:
                _email.recipient = answer.Split('|')[1].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                //возвращаем ошибку 
                SendData(answer);
          //      l.WriteEvent("<<<" + answer + "\n Получателя почты не удалось определить", threadName);
            }
            break;

        case "DATA":
            _commandWorking.DATA(argsText, threadName);
            //отправить СМС
            Finish(threadName);
            break;

        case "BDAT":
            _commandWorking.BDAT(argsText, threadName);
            //отправить СМС
            Finish(threadName);

            break;

        case "RSET":
            answer = _commandWorking.RSET();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "VRFY":
            answer = _commandWorking.VRFY();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "EXPN":
            answer = _commandWorking.EXPN();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "HELP":
            answer = _commandWorking.HELP();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "NOOP":
            answer = _commandWorking.NOOP();
            SendData(answer);
            break;

        case "QUIT":
            answer = _commandWorking.QUIT();
            SendData(answer);                    

         //   l.WriteEvent("***************** Закрыта сессия " + _email.sessionId.ToString() + " *****************\n", threadName);
            l.WriteEvent(">>> Закрыта сессия: " + _email.sessionId.ToString(), threadName);

            _clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
           // _clientSocket.Dispose();

            break;

        default:
            SendData("500 command unrecognized\r\n");
            l.WriteEvent("500 command unrecognized: " + SMTP_command, threadName);
            _clientSocket.Close();
         //   _clientSocket.Dispose();
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            break;
    }
}
```

По моему схема простая, но где-то просчет у меня.  Мне подсказали, что может я потоки "размножаю", но по идее не так.

Как можно увеличить производительность?

UPD - так я считываю команды клиента

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Считываем команду клиента
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string ReadLine()
        {
            try
            {
                long lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                ArrayList lineBuf = new ArrayList();
                byte prevByte = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (_clientSocket.Available > 0)
                    {
                        // Read next byte
                        byte[] currByte = new byte[1];
                        int countRecieved = _clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);

                        // Count must be equal. Eg. some computers won't give byte at first read attempt
                        if (countRecieved == 1)
                        {
                            lineBuf.Add(currByte[0]);

                            // Line found
                            if ((prevByte == (byte)'\r' && currByte[0] == (byte)'\n'))
                            {
                                byte[] retVal = new byte[lineBuf.Count - 2];    // Remove <CRLF> 
                                lineBuf.CopyTo(0, retVal, 0, lineBuf.Count - 2);


                                return Encoding.Default.GetString(retVal).Trim();
                            }

                            // Store byte
                            prevByte = currByte[0];

                            // reset last data time
                            lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //---- Time out stuff -----------------------//
                        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > lastDataTime + ((long)(60000)) * 10000)
                        {
                                                        return ""; 
                        }
                        //Thread.Sleep(100);
                        //------------------------------------------//
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                l.WriteEvent("EROR ReadLine(): " + x.ToString());
                throw new Exception(x.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Для начала пройдитесь профайлером.

Comment: Каким профайлером? Не понял

Comment: @LeonardBertone, Вам говорят о том, что нужно выполнить [профилирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%28%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29) программы. Это должно выявить проблемные места. Тогда постановка задачи будет уже более конкретной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_clientSocket.Available` как работает? Ждёт когда что-то появится или сразу возвращает 0?
У вас циклы без передышки вызывают и вызывают `_clientSocket.Available`. Это и пожирает весь процессор.
Надо сначала попытаться что-то прочитать блокирующим методом, или ждать событие при асинхронном методе.
При блокирующем методе (у Вас походу именно такой) во первых строках цикла должно быть:

```
while(true) {
    byte[] currByte = new byte[1];
    int countRecieved = _clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);
    if (countRecieved == 0) {
        // Другая сторона закрыла сокет
        // Здесь должен быть выход из цикла
    }
```

`Receive` остановит поток и будет ждать поступление данных, не нагружая процессор.
`_clientSocket.Available` Вам вообще не нужен.
На первый взгляд достаточно убрать все эти `if (_clientSocket.Available > 0)`

Comment: Через _clientSocket.Available я определяю, есть ли данные для считывания.  Получается, что он постоянно работает и ждет, когда  _clientSocket.Available будет больше 0

Comment: Я если честно не представляю, как еще сделать  прием команд от клиента

Comment: @LeonardBertone Полно же учебных заметок по работе с вводом-выводом и сокетами в том числе. Такого как у Вас вообще нигде нет! Вот страницы MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172494(v=vs.90).aspx Пример сервера https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx Другие примеры https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Убрал clientSocket.Available, не помогло, кушает ресурсы как и прежде

Comment: Может senddata в таком же духе исполнена? available из обоих циклов убрали? И просмотрите на другие возможности зацикливания.

Comment: `Receive` может вернут 0, если сокет закрыт с другой стороны через `Shutdown`. Это приведёт к зацикливанию. Надо сделать  проверку `countRecieved == 0` И надо вернуть какое-то значение, пустую строку, null, чтобы проверить во внешнем цикле тоже для выхода. Или исключение выкинуть.

Comment: Ещё с закрытием что-то совсем не то. `_clientSocket.Disconnect(true)` не закроет сокет, а всего лишь даст установку как поступить с ним после закрытия. Для закрытия сокета  рекомендуется выполнить `_clientSocket.Shutdown(both);` `_clientSocket.Close();` Из-за того что сокет не закрывается поток продолжает гонять цикл.